# VSCode не дает подсказки созданной переменной. Помогите исправить эту проблему

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Я создаю переменную firstName .
Пишу console.log(fir) - на этом этапе нету подсказки firstName.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто знает в чем проблема ? И как можно исправить?

Comment: только javascript не показывает?

Comment: Есть результат какой? Справились с проблемой?

Comment: @Dmitry та не , это походу особенности снипетов

Comment: а ctrl + пробел?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить плагин AllAutoComplate и js сниппеты

Comment: тут дело не в снипете(

Comment: Тогда просто плагин AllAutoComplate

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется или вы забыли поставить точку с запятой (;) в конце объявления переменной firstName.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте установить расширение для javascript. Например, вот это: [JS-CSS-HTML Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter)
.

Если владеете английским, то можно почитать вот это [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)

Я использую тот форматер, который указан в самом начале. Проблем пока не испытывал. Только проверьте настройки после установки:

Нажмите <kbd>F1</kbd> в интерфейсе VSCode. В появившейся строке напишите `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`
откроется файл и вот эти строки должны присутствовать, если нет - добавьте.

```json
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter"
    },
```

Указаный выше форматтер только мое личное предпочтение, вы также можете найти и другие. Здесь вы также сможете найти рекомендации для javascript - [автоимпорт](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_auto-imports). Но это к сожалаению на английском и это касается встроенного модуля изначально в VSCode

И еще одна мысля появилась, попробуйте вот так:

1. Нажмите <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, а затем сразу <kbd>m</kbd>
2. Откроется вот такое окно
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Выберите `Configure File Assosiation for '.js'...`
4. Выберите из списка нужное дополнение[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно сработать.